# Enable configuration property in test without loading full Spring Boot application context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

Assume we have Spring Boot application and want to load only specific slice of application context.

Particularly load YAML file configuration and map `spring.datasource` to `DataSourceProperties` marked by `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Naive not working declaration of test is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceProperties.class},
    loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class,
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application.yaml", "classpath:application-dev.yaml"})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({DataSourceProperties.class})
@Slf4j
public class HibernateTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    @Test
    public void dataSourceTest() throws SQLException {
        log.info("DS URL: {}", dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
    }
}
```

`application-dev.yaml` has:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/APP
```

Test prints:

```
DS URL: null
```

I am looking for a way to map YAML config to  `@ConfigurationProperties` marked class (`DataSourceProperties`) and make it used by `@Configuration` class (`DataSourceAutoConfiguration`) without loading any other services/components/etc...

Comment: why don't you use `excludeFilters={
  @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=Foo.class)` in component scan

Comment: @Deadpool It's what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to search for excludes if I need only 2 to include!

Comment: can you be more specific please, exclude will not create beans for that classes

Comment: Why don't you just use the out-of-the-box support for testing application slices, e.g. `@DataJpaTest`and `@WebMvcTest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those links  answer my questions:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13912
  Add support for YAML files to @PropertySource (Resolution: Unresolved).
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16563
  Document that @PropertySource and @TestPropertySource do not support YAML.
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12388
  Property Override not Working For YML Files.
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10772
  Map properties in yaml from TestPropertySource not working in boot 2.0.0.

In short Spring Framework developers don't want to support YAML format for `@TestPropertySource` & `@PropertySource` annotation explaining that YAML support in Spring Boot made in tricky way / broken way (though I lost in explanations).

After switching code to use `.properties` files my test works fine.